# Matplotlib line not being picked up by the 'pick_event' handler

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, line

I'm trying to create a line from one point to another where if it is clicked, it is removed from the plot. I have a plot that creates a simple line but for some reason, it isn't picked up with the event handle 'pick_event' when it is clicked on. Here's what I have:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x1 = 1
x2 = 2
y1 = 1
y2 = 1
z1 = 2
z2 = 2

ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], [z1, z2], linewidth=2)


def on_pick(event):
    event.artist.set_visible(not event.artist.get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

This is pretty simple as it is but basically, I need to be able to create lines by just giving it x, y, and z coordinates from one point to another. Why is this line not being pickup 'pick_event' handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it is too hard to click on a line then set picker tolerance:

```
...
# set 5 points tolerance
ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], [z1, z2], linewidth=2, picker=5)
...
```

Comment: Thanks Serenity, this is exactly what I needed:)